# How to import old libgdx games eclipse project into android studio?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx, android-module

I'm trying to import old LibGDX eclipse Android games to Android Studio. Some games are easily able to import all module (android , core) and run but some are not able to import, only one android module is being imported . I'm trying to import as a eclipse project.

Comment: When I switched from Eclipse to Android Studio I simply installed new project and then copied my source code and assets. First you'll start with empty project and can easily know that source of your problems is not in your code if it happens. And second, you'll have the latest version of LibGDX. I had to adjust code a bit (bacause of newer LibGDX version), but it worth it.

Comment: It depends on how old the other project is, you could use the `build.gradle` file to import your project.